# Watching computed properties

Tags: vue-component, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have a component with the following hash

```
{ 
  computed: { 
    isUserID: { 
      get: function(){
         return this.userId? 
      } 
  }
}
```

Should I be watching `isUserID` or `userId` for changes? Can you watch computed properties?

Comment: It will be really helpful to answer if you can elaborate what you are trying to do. Here when getting you are getting `this.ID` while setting `this.userId`, I am not sure how will this work.

Comment: @saurabh I was trying to set a data property either by route params or component "props" since I can't do both I was thinking of just using a computed property and watch it. But what i really wanted to know was can you watch a computed property?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Yes, you can setup [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/3jz0nfcf/).

Following is the code to set watch on computed property:

```js
const demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',

    data() {
        return {
            age: ''
        };
    },

    computed: {
        doubleAge() {
            return 2 * this.age;
        }
    },

    watch: {
        doubleAge(newValue) {
            alert(`yes, computed property changed: ${newValue}`);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this again sometimes I am not able to get the events of the computed property so I have to end up using a data property instead which is usually a duplicate of a computed property. Is there any reason why a computed property fail triggering a watch event?

Comment: @Kendall I am not sure why that will happen, if you can put relevant code where it is not working, than someone might point out some caveat or bug.

Comment: I eventually re worked  the code to compensate. Will try to upload the original code when I get through with some other stuff

Comment: @Kendall I met the same issues, the change of computed not trigger the watch handler, do you have any progress on this?

Comment: @Kendall It seems like once an error was thrown in the computed function, then it won't trigger the watcher anymore, plz see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j7pLbtdz/

Comment: Should be noted there are quite few instances which will not trigger a reaction. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html -- I had to use `Vue.set`/`this.$set`.

Comment: I have only had issues watching a computed property when it contained an object. Then I had to do a deep watch:
`watch:{ myComputedProperty : { handler(newVal){ //do something when change happens}, deep: true}}`

Comment: @CindyConway: there is a case where not even a deep watcher does work, namely when the computed property returns different objects.

Comment: The watch doesn't trigger for the initialization (on page load). To fix this, you have to add `immediate: true` as explained [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/watchers-not-triggered-on-initialization/12475/3)

Comment: @a.l. I was having that exact problem. I'm so glad I found your comment! Avoiding an error within the handler solved the issue of the watcher of a computed property not watching.

Answer (score 7):

```
computed: {
  name: {
    get: function(){
      return this.name;
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  name: function(){
    console.log('changed');
  }
}
```

This way we can watch over the computed property if it is changed we get notified on the console.

Comment: I'm a newbie so don't know the options much now I think it looks better.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you do it in Vue 3 with Composition API:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'

const variable = ref(1)

const computedProperty = computed(() => {
  return variable.value * 2
})

watch(computedProperty, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log('computedProperty was ' + oldValue + '. Now it is ' + newValue + '.')
})
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="variable++">Click me</button>
</template>
```