# Computed property in Vue is not triggering a watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067378/watching-computed-properties), it shouldn't be a problem to watch a computed property. And yet my code isn't working.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="product" class="section">
        <form>
            <div class="control"><input type="text" class="input" v-model="title"></div>
            <div class="control"><input type="text" class="input" v-model="description"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: null,
            description: null
        }
    },
    computed: {
        product() {
            // const payload = { collection: 'products', id: this.$route.params.productId }
            // return this.$store.getters.objectFromId(payload)
            console.log('working')
            return { title: 'Awesome Title', description: 'Awesome Description' }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        product() {
            this.title = this.product.title,
            this.description = this.product.description
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm expecting the `watch` to trigger when `product` is returned, but it doesn't.

I could set the properties in the computed property like so:

```
computed: {
    product() {
        const payload = { collection: 'products', id: this.$route.params.productId }
        const product = this.$store.getters.objectFromId(payload)
        this.title = product.title
        this.description = product.description
        return product
    }
}
```

But then the compiler gives me a warning: `error: Unexpected side effect in "product" computed property`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be a more straightforward solution to your problem

Comment: I've updated my post to more clearly display intent. I'm trying to get a product and set some inital data() that are bound to some form inputs. I **could** set values within the compute function but I get this annoying side effect warning in the compiler. I believe it's bad practice to set properties in a get?

Comment: You would need to [use a watcher](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XBpodo?editors=1010) with `immediate` set in order to get your watcher to fire on the initial render.

Comment: Maybe you really want title and description to be computed values with both getters and setters.

Comment: @HamishJohnson you don't use computed for that. Have a look at created/mounted vue.js hooks. Inside them you can load external data and attach it to the current data model

Comment: @Enrico Yeah I have to agree with you there - not really sure why I chose computed in this instance. Thanks

Comment: @HamishJohnson have you come up with a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Enrico I did, I put it in created() instead, as per your suggestion - if you want to answer the question I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @Bert: to me, your answer is spot on. I prefer it to the accepted answer, because this could allow given component's parameters being reactive beyond the creative or mounted life-cycle hooks. IMO it'd be nice, if you proposed it as a main answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to OP's comments, his intention is to get and load some initial data.
The common way to achieve this behavior is to place it inside `created or mounted` vuejs lifecycle hooks.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="product" class="section">
        <form>
            <div class="control"><input type="text" class="input" v-model="title"></div>
            <div class="control"><input type="text" class="input" v-model="description"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            description: ''
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.getInitialData();
        this.foo();

        console.log("created!");
    },

    methods: {
        getInitialData: function(){
            const payload = {
                collection: 'products', 
                id: this.$route.params.productId 
            };
            var product = this.$store.getters.objectFromId(payload);
            this.title = product.title;
            this.description = product.description;
        },
        foo: function(){// ...}
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
watch: {
    product: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(value) { 
            updateCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is a bit all over the place. `product` is a computed, so it runs whenever it's source values change. (You have no control over when it runs.) It shouldn't have side effects (assignments `this.description`, `this.title`), or trigger network requests.

The code in `product` is fetching your source data. This belongs in `methods`, linked explicitly to a user action or a lifecyle event.

Why do you need to copy your data (`this.description = product.description` in `watch:product`)? Vue works best when you have your data (your app state) outside Vue, in a global variable say. Then your Vue components just transparently reflect whatever the app state is at a given moment.

Hope this helps.