# setTimeout for v-alert after adding Item to an array basket

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, settimeout

this is my `rightTableMenu` template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 align="center">{{ title }}</h1>
    <v-alert type="info" icon="mdi-emoticon-sad" v-if="basketStatus">
      Empty Basket, please add some to basket
    </v-alert>
    <div v-if="changeAlertStatus()">
      <v-alert
        type="success"
        icon="mdi-emoticon-happy"
        :value="alert"
        transition="fade-transition"
      >
        thank you
      </v-alert>
      <v-simple-table>
        <template v-slot:default>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left">Quantity</th>
              <th class="text-left">Name</th>
              <th class="text-left">Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in basket" :key="item.name">
              <td>
                <v-icon @click="increaseQuantity(item)">add_box</v-icon>
                <span>{{ item.quantity }}</span>
                <v-icon @click="decreaseQuantity(item)"
                  >indeterminate_check_box
                </v-icon>
              </td>
              <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ (item.price * item.quantity).toFixed(2) }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </template>
      </v-simple-table>
      <v-divider color="black"></v-divider>
      <v-row id="basket_checkout" style="margin: 0">
        <v-col>
          <p>Subtotal:</p>
          <p>Delivery:</p>
          <p>Total amount:</p>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="text-right">
          <p>${{ subTotalResult }}</p>
          <p>$10</p>
          <p class="font-weight-bold">${{ totalPriceResult }}</p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn depressed class="orange" v-on:click="submitOrder">
          <v-icon>shopping_basket</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

as you see there are two alerts one is showing when there is not item inside the array basket by checking the following

```
basketStatus() {
  return this.$store.getters.basket.length === 0;
},
```

which is computed property 
my data property section is

```
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Current Basket",
      alert: false,
    };
  },
```

but for the second v-alert, I wanna to have the alert to be shown and disappear after few sec and so far I have done the following for it

```
  async changeAlertStatus() {
      if (this.$store.getters.basket.length !== 0) {
        this.alert = true;
        try {
          const response = await setTimeout(() => {
            this.alert = false;
          }, 100);
          console.log("this is the resonse " + response);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("fetch failed", err);
        }
      } else {
        this.alert = false;
      }
    },
```

which is a method 
I am confused how to interject the function inside the div part without using v-if directive and my async changeAlertStatus gets in the infinite loop when I check it inside the console and the v-alert does not get disappear

[image]

any thoughts on that?

if there is more info needed , please let me know

thank you

just in case my `leftTableMenu` is follows

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="showError['situation']">
    <!-- 
basically, when you close the alert, the value of the alert goes to false
so you need to turn it to true when there is an error  :value="showError.situation" -->
      <app-alert :text="showError.message"  :value.sync="showError.situation"></app-alert>
    </div>
    <h1 align="center">{{ title }}</h1>
    <v-simple-table od="menu-table">
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Price</th>
            <th class="text-left">Add</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.name">
            <td>
              <span id="id_name">{{ item.name }}</span>
              <br />
              <span id="menu_item_description">{{ item.description }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
            <td>
              <v-btn text v-on:click="addToBasket(item)">
                <v-icon color="orange">1add_shopping_cart</v-icon>
                <span></span>
              </v-btn>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LeftTableMenu',
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Menu Items", 
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addToBasket(item) {
      this.$store.dispatch("addToBasket", item);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    showError() {
      return this.$store.getters.showError;
    },
    menuItems() {
      return this.$store.getters.menuItems;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: not sure why you're calling a function(?) `changeAlerStatus()` in a `v-if` if it's also not returning anything. Also, do you actually know what a setTimeout does? Why are you awaiting a response from it?

Comment: @A. Lau I am new in vue js and I did not know better except using v-if . yest setTimeout puts the task at the end of thread so it is gonna be ran later. cuz I wanna it to disappear after few sec as I mentioned. I totally agree changeAlertStatus does not return anything, but how can I use it inside the div to check if the array is empty or not?

Comment: you don't need to await a setTimeout, it does not return a promise. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp  Also, computed values aren't functions, they're just values, so there's no need to invoke them. Your `changeAlertStatus()` should be changed to `alert` in the v-if. Should at least prevent the infinite loop

Comment: how can I disappear it after few sec?

Comment: put your setTimeout logic into a watcher that watches `basketStatus` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: you know that basketStatus is computed property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212996/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-a-lau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a watcher on your computed property to see if it's changed.

When it changes you can update your data to show or the "Success" alert and then set a timeout to hide it back again after some time.

Here is an updated example with some changed param names for clarity.

I changed the computed name to be **emptyBasket**

```
computed: {
  emptyBasket() {
    return this.$store.getters.basket.length === 0;
  }
},
```

I added **showSuccessAlert** to data

```
data() {
  return {
    showSuccessAlert: false
  };
},
```

And here it the watcher that updates the **showSuccessAlert**

```
watch: {
  emptyBasket: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.showSuccessAlert = !newVal;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showSuccessAlert = oldVal;
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

The watcher will be triggered immediately (not sure you need it),
`newVal` and `oldVal` are representing the new and old state of `emptyBasket`.
So when `newVal` is `false` it means that the basket is not empty, hence the update of `showSuccessAlert = !newVal`

I created a simple working sandbox with your code.

Here is the link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-cherry-ngpqu?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: what immediate does inside watch?

Comment: with one only change it worked for me that I negated the value oldVal inside the setTimeout

Comment: I put v-if=!basketStatus inside outer div and put v-if inside alert

Answer (score 1):

Should probably be watching `backStatus` and then do your alert stuff

```
watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    backStatus: function (newVal, oldVal) {
        this.alert = newVal;
        const response = setTimeout(() => {
            this.alert = oldVal;
        }, 100); 
        // swap the vals around if needed
    }
}
```

maybe you might need immediate too, but that's up to how your want to display things.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: what is newVal and oldVal here as an example?

Comment: read the documentation. The variable name is pretty self explanatory as well. But in this example, it will be true/false since that's what your backStatus is passing

Comment: basketStatus is computed property that I cannot add it to my watch as far as I search for cuz it is not in data property to watch for. so any thoughts on that?

Comment: pretty sure you can. Have you even tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067378/watching-computed-properties

Comment: I will I updated my post cuz the menu is consist of two components right and left menu

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `changeAlertStatus` in the `v-if` directive, can that just be bound to the `this.alert` property? Then, when the Add to Cart button is clicked, its callback can set `this.alert` to true, causing the alerts to display. Just after setting `this.alert` to true, register the setTimeout to revert it back to false

Example: (Please excuse the abstract-ness of it, I feel like this is some missing code from the original post, specifically the add to cart button)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="alerts" v-if="alert">
      <div>Thank you</div>
    </div>
    <button @click="handleAddToCart">
      Add to cart
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    alert: false,
    basketStatus: false
  },
  methods: {
    handleAddToCart() {
      this.alert = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.alert = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: could you gimme a sample or elaborate your answer more plz?

Comment: @KickButtowski I have updated my response with a basic code example, hopefully that helps

Comment: can you join the chat please?

Comment: I didn't know there is a chat! Where would I find that?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212996/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-a-lau

Comment: I used your sample and completely my left panel disappear ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this timeout on alert using watch like the others guys said:

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full">

    <div class="w-full" v-for="item in cart" :key="item.id">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full p-2 bg-yellow" v-if="alert">
      <p>Your cart is empty</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'CartList',
  data() {
    return {
      cart: [],
      alert: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    cart(val) {
      if(!val.length) {
        this.alert = true
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
         this.alert = false
        }, 2000)
      }

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCart()
  },
  methods: {
    getCart() {
      axios('/cart/get').then((response) => {
        this.cart = response.data.cart
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But you can add some extra code to your request function and add the timeout there too:

```
getCart() {
  axios('/cart/get')
  .then((response) {
    if(response.data.cart.length) {
      setTimeout( () => { 
        this.alert = false
      }, 2000)
    }
  })
}
```